# When reading file, Why ReadBytes affect the following Read?

Tags: go

When reading file by chunks, using `reader.Read`, it reads 32KB for each calling.
But if I use `reader.ReadBytes`, it reduces the number of bytes reads by next `reader.Read` to 3KB.

Another question: Why **can't** I read more than 32KB using `reader.Read` and `bufio.NewReaderSize` ?

My Code:

```
func SomeFunc () {
    gzfile , err := os.Open(SomeFile)
    ErrorPanic (err)
    input_file , err := gzip.NewReader(gzfile)
    ErrorPanic (err)
    // reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(input_file, 120 * 1024 * 1024) //120MB
    reader := bufio.NewReader(input_file)

    .....

    eof := false
    for !eof {
        var n int
        // line := make ([]byte,100 * 1024 * 1024) //100MB
        line := make ([]byte,32 * 1024) //32KB
        n , err = reader.Read (line)
        eof = is_eof (err)
        _ , err = buffer.Write (line)
    /***/ fmt.Println("len (line)= " , len (line) , " ; n= ",n)
        line = []byte{}
        ErrorNotice (err)

        eos := false
        for !eof && !eos {
            line , err = reader.ReadBytes('\n')
            eof = is_eof (err)

            if SomeCond {
                .....

                buffer.Reset()
                eos = true
            }
            _ , err = buffer.Write (line)
            ErrorNotice (err)
        }
    }
}

func ErrorPanic(err error) .....
func ErrorNotice (err error) .....
func is_eof (err error) bool .....
```

The output when calling `ReadBytes('\n')`:

```
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  32768
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  3782
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  2966
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  2835
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  2756
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  3513
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  2583
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  3247
```

The output when **not** calling `ReadBytes('\n')`:

```
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  32768
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  32768
len (line)=  32768  ; n=  32768
```

Comment: An `io.Reader`'s `Read` method is allowed to return as few bytes as it likes: `Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)` can return any `n` such that`0 <= n <= len(p)`; it's allowed to use [the phase of the moon](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pom&sektion=6) to decide how many bytes to return on any given call if it wanted to. You need to check how many bytes get returned (e.g. do `line = line[:n]` before using it) or if you require a specific amount use something like [`io.ReadFull`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull).

Answer (score 1):

Because it designed like this. On read may read any byte count. thinking `reader` is a interface, and the `reader.Read()` need satisfy all implement.